# Add PowerBI into Powerpoint

Tags: powerbi, powerpoint

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to embed my PowerBI dashboard into Powerpoint slide. I copied the share report URL from PowerBI and pasted it in PowerBI add-in in Powerpoint. However, I received the error as shown in the screenshot above. I restarted the office application for few time but the issue is still there. Both Powerpoint and PowerBI are using the same office 365 account. Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you on a corporate network?

Comment: yes, in my office

Comment: It could be disabled in the tenant settings. I'll post a screenshot in the answer as I can't do so in comments.

Comment: I edited this post to remove an unrelated tag.  Please take care adding tags in future.

Answer (score 0):

It could be disabled in the tenant settings.
[image]

Comment: Where can I enable it?

Comment: You need to be an Admin. On the Power BI Service, there is a cog in the top right corner and in there is an option for Admin Settings.